# How to change screen brightness based on screen colors?

Tags: 12.04, brightness, automation

I would like to know if there is any way to change the screen brightness based on the screen predominant color.

For example if I am browsing a web page with a lot of white color decrease the brightness but if I using some text editor with dark background for example, increase the brightness.

I have tried Redshift but is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found something like this so I decided to create a solution. It currently only works in Windows but I am working on a Linux version. You can email me if you have any questions or want to help! https://github.com/dragondgold/BrightnessController-Java